# Render contents of arrays in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Lets assume I got an array holding 5000 objects. I want to render a table containing all attributes of the contained objects as a table row `<td>`. Is it possible to somehow return the current row of `<td>` within each iteration and immediately render the output to the browser. So that you could see the table getting larger at the screen for each of the 5000 objects?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to somehow return the current row of  within each iteration and immediately render the output to the browser. So that you could see the table getting larger at the screen for each of the 5000 objects

Yes. Use the `key` attribute so that the DOM for existing objects doesn't need to change : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html